# Publish to Facebook Page using OpenGraph Action

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress

I have a Wordpress blog (self hosted) and  we use the Facebook Wordpress plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook/). I have set up an app on Facebook and setup the publish action which has been approved.
All seems to work as expected, I have set it to post to my Timeline when post is made public, and I have authorized it to post to my page (http://facebook.com/dannicaandsusanspage), where I am a Manager.

The issue is that when the post is posted to my Timeline is says 'Shaine Fisher published an article on Mommy & Daddy's Blog.' but when it posts to the page it says 'Mommy & Daddy's Page shared a link'

I would like the page to show that 'Mommy & Daddy's Page published an article on Mommy & Daddy's Blog.'

Facebook support sent me here, so I am asking you for any advice, is this the designed behaviour? Or am I missing something?

Thanks for your assistance.
Shaine

Comment: I feel I should add that it is not a typo, the Facebook page is called 'Mommy & Daddy's Page' whereas the Facebook App AND Wordpress site are called 'Mommy & Daddy's Blog'

That was just for clarification.

Shaine

Comment: I would like advice if this question is worded incorrectly or missing any vital information. Surely this isn't just a one off incident, I can find other questions but no solutions.
Shaine